# How To ? Add PDF page no within iframe using react js

Tags: reactjs, npm, iframe

I want to add pageno in iframe using reactjs. What can I do?

```
// If 'image' is available, display another Iframe with the option to set the page number.
    <Iframe
      className="iframes"
      url={`${image}?page=2`} // Replace '2' with the desired page number
      width="100%"
      type="application/pdf"
      id="myId"
      height="500px"
      display="initial"
      position="relative"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#` instead of `?` to open the PDF for that specific page.